# How to Update multiple entries in a table in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application that is trying to update multiple users at a time in User table.
I tried giving multiple ids separated with ',' ,but fails and getting error like "no route matches", i have created a custom method "assign" , with route specified as ,

```
"assign/:id" => "users#assign" , :via => [:put]
```

I am trying to update through POSTMAN REST Client.

My PUT Request,

```
http://localhost:3000/assign/6,7,8    ---   PUT
```

data:

```
{
   "users":[
    {
       "trainerid":4
    },
    {
       "trainerid":5
    },
    {
       "trainerid":6
    }
    ]
}
```

Mu Controller

```
def assign
    @ids = params[:id].split(",")
    @users = params[:users]
    @ids.each_with_index do |i|
      @user = User.find(i)
      @user.updateattributes(@users[index])
    end
    render :json => { :status => :ok, :message => "User Updated Successfully"}.to_json 
end
```

Here i am trying to update `trainerid` in users table with `id: 4 ,5 ,6`

Is it possible to update in another way.

Any help is appreciated.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why put the IDs in the URL? Splitting the string feels wrong. Why not just have a simpler route, just to users/assign? Then in your JSON you can have:

```
{ "users":[
  { "id":6, "trainer_id":4 },
  { "id":7, "trainer_id":5 },
  { "id":8, "trainer_id":6 }
]}
```

And deal with it thus:

```
def assign
  params[:users].each do |hash|
    User.find(hash['id']).update_attributes hash
  end
end
```

Obviously it needs error handling etc, but that's the basic method. Note that [update_attributes will only update those attributes flagged as attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes#185-Only-attr-accessible-attributes-will-be-updated), so you don't have to worry about the IDs' presence in the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your route and it doesn't give me a routing error. Here is what I have:

```
match "assign/:id" => "users#assign" , :via => [:put]
```

With this route, a request to `assign/1,2,3` correctly routes to the `assign` action of the controller. At that point, you need to split `params[:id]` (as you have done).

However, you don't need to be using instance variables and you don't need `each_with_index`:

```
def assign
  ids = params[:id].split(",")
  users = params[:users]
  ids.each do |i|
    user = User.find(i)
    user.update_attributes(users[index])
  end
  render :json => { :status => :ok, :message => "User Updated Successfully"}.to_json
end
```

However, I posted this answer just to say that this *can* be done. Honestly though, I share @micapam's opinion that you really don't need to be splitting ids like this.

Answer (score 0):

the route

```
"assign/:id" => "users#assign" , :via => [:put]
```

can get only one id at a time.. You cannot pass multiple ids for this route..

Answer (score 0):

Update the routes to use edit_multiple and update_multiple actions:

```
resources :users do
  get edit_multiple, :on => :collection
  post update_multiple, :on => :collection
end
```

Now create the edit_multiple action that sets up the @users instance variable with the user data to be updated:

```
def edit_multiple
  @users = User.all #get the users with specified criteria.
end
```

In your edit_multiple.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag :action => "update_multiple" do %>
  <% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
    <%= fields_for "user[#{index}]", user do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => user.id %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :dob %><br />
        <%= f.date_select :dob %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <%end%> 
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In controller:

```
def update_multiple
  @users = {}
  error_count = 0

  params[:users].values.each do |user_params|
    user = User.find(user_params[:id])
    unless user.update_attributes(user_params)
      error_count += 1 #increment error count if fails to update
    end
    @users << user #add user to @users array to render the edit if fails
  end

  if error_count == 0
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => 'Users saved successfully'
  else
    render :edit_multiple #@users will play its role here
  end
end
```

It may not be the best approach. Hope this will help. You can use JSON response too.